# ViewPager, Fragments and Adapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have 20 pages in ViewPager, each page is a Fragment and contains 5 views. Now, I fetch something from server and add view to this ViewPager. I call notifyDataSetChanged(), but that sometimes results buggy, views are moved wrongly after that. 
I've read this http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html but cannot find how to implement POSITION_CHANGED. Can anyone point me on good tutorial on FragmentPagerAdapter implementation when we add/move elements?

Thanks.